# Qual a diferença entre JavaJDK e OpenJDK?

Tags: java

Andei pesquisando e pelo que vi ambos são mantidos pele Oracle... Mas se o java também é código aberto, qual a necessidade do OpenJDK? Ou estou equivocado quanto ao Java se código aberto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nada crucial. O projeto openjdk é baseado principalmente no código-fonte hotspot doado pela Sun.

Além disso, o openjdk foi selecionado para ser a implementação de [referência para o java 7](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/moving_to_openjdk_as_the), e é mantido pelos engenheiros da Oracle.

Há uma resposta mais detalhada à sua pergunta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547458/what-is-the-difference-between-jvm-jdk-jre-openjdk) (em inglês), que liga a esta postagem no blog:

> P: Qual é a diferença entre o código-fonte encontrado no repositório OpenJDK e o código que você usa para construir o JDK do Oracle?
>
> R: É muito próximo - o nosso processo de compilação para as versões do Oracle JDK baseia-se no OpenJDK 7, acrescentando apenas um par de peças, como o código de implantação, que inclui a implementação do Oracle Plugin Java e WebStart Java, bem como alguns terceira fonte fechada Como um rasterizador de gráficos, alguns componentes de terceiros de código aberto, como o Rhino, e alguns pedaços aqui e ali, como documentação adicional ou fontes de terceiros. Em frente, nossa intenção é abrir todas as fontes do Oracle JDK, exceto aquelas que consideramos recursos comerciais como o JRockit Mission Control (ainda não disponível no Oracle JDK) e substituir componentes de terceiros bloqueados por alternativas de código aberto para conseguir uma paridade mais próxima Entre as bases de código.

Traduzido de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Diego!!

Comment: por nada, abraços